# Code wrapping in Quarto pdf output documents

Tags: python, latex, quarto

Suppose we have the following `qmd` document:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
---

```{python}
#| eval: false
print('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dapibus feugiat nibh, sed gravida ipsum rutrum nec. Donec tincidunt arcu scelerisque enim tempor blandit. Donec a neque facilisis, interdum leo et, luctus erat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer ac nunc eu orci luctus feugiat.')
```
````

How can the python code be wrapped in the output pdf file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can make use of latex package [`fvextra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fvextra) suggested [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4302#issuecomment-360799891)

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
include-in-header: 
  text: |
    \usepackage{fvextra}
    \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}
---

```{python}
#| eval: false
print('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dapibus feugiat nibh, sed gravida ipsum rutrum nec. Donec tincidunt arcu scelerisque enim tempor blandit. Donec a neque facilisis, interdum leo et, luctus erat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer ac nunc eu orci luctus feugiat.')
```
````

---

[image: long line of code autobreaked (i.e. wrapped)]

---

Comment: Thanks (+1). Note this solution also works within `_quarto.yml` files for [Quarto](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/pdf-basics.html)